# partitioning in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

hi experts just a quick question, I bought a new laptop Windows 7. I was using win xp for the last 10 years. Previously a friend of mine setup my Win xp and on my laptop he made a partition for drive C, D (data) & E for restore

What I would like to know is, is it practical to do a partition in Win 7? Some of my colleagues said that it is not common to do it anymore as it is Win 7. Would appreciate your suggestions? Thanks

Comment: tintincutes: Some new laptops like HP already have 4 primary partitions, so adding a partition can be difficult, make your Recovery Discs and back up data before you attempt adding a partition.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of personal preference nowadays.

Personally I do not see the point of assigning multiple partitions on the same physical disk to the same OS, as it does not protect your data any more than one single partition does. That being said, if you intend on rolling back or wiping your OS on a regular basis, but dont want to invest in a whole separate disk, creating a data partition could still be useful.

As to a technical reason for doing it? There is none. Just a decision based on how you intend to use your computer going forward.

Me, I avoided the whole question entirely by having my OS loaded on a 120gb SSD for speed and all my data on other disks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't recommend partitioning client drives anymore. The arguments in favor of partitioning are usually separation of operating system and user data, which is absolutely valid in principle. However, Windows unfortunately makes it quite hard to actually do this. Sure, you can relocate a user profile. But you still can't re-integrate that profile after a reinstall, so you haven't actually gained anything.

My recommendation is: create a separate folder on the same volume for your user data and put your backups on an external disk.